# s3, need to download from browser, 10GB limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download

I'm in a bit of a pinch. I'm stuck using a computer that doesn't have the necessary CLI capabilities to download files from S3 (IT restrictions on what I can put on the computer). Hence, I can only download a file via the browser.

Problem: when I try to download a file that is >10Gb, I get an error. I'm guessing that there's a limit to the size of file I'm downloading (I have plenty of drive space for this, so it isn't a space issue).

How can I resolve this? Is there a setting on the browser that I need to change? Or something in S3 that I need to change? Thanks!

Comment: "I get an error".  Include the exact error message, please.  Also the browser and version you are using.

Comment: "I get an error" is like "How long is a piece of string?" - what error do you get? :) more than happy to help then

Comment: Whoops, sorry, forgot to include the error message. I get "failed - forbidden" at the bottom of the Chrome browser I'm using. version 95.0.4638.54

Comment: How are you doing it in the browser? Are you going via the S3 management console? Or are you simply entering a URL in the browser that points to an S3 object? Please Edit your question to provide full details so that we can assist you.

Comment: There is no such 10G limit on the S3. When in the tightly controlled environment - are you using a proxy/socks server? Isn't a limit enforced on the network level?

Comment: Thanks All, it sounds like maybe this is more of an issue within the environment I'm working (our company was recently purchased, and there are still a lot of IT nuances we're learning). I'll reach out to our IT organization for further clarification. Thanks again!